# how to load all flatfils, if anyone of the files got failed(package won't fail) then skip the file and load the reaming files in SSIS?

Tags: ssis, stack, ssis-2012

I've to load data from multiple files into a table thorough for each loop container in SSIS. If anyone of the files got error-ed out then the package stops execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "ForceExecutionResult" and "MaximumErrorCount" or "Propagate system variable" Options.

You can see the full example in this site [Continue a Foreach loop after an error in a SQL Server Integration Services package](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3575/continue-a-foreach-loop-after-an-error-in-a-sql-server-integration-services-package/)

> "In this tip we presented two options to continue a loop in SQL Server Integration Services when an error occurs. You can either make the package insensitive to errors by using the properties MaximumErrorCount and ForceExecutionResult, or you could stop the propagation of errors to higher levels in the package by creating an empty event handler and setting the Propagate system variable to False. The last option is the preferred option for robust error handling."...